# should I change the config.lua file's width and height to contentWidth and contentHeight

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am making an app and i just recently stumbled across the config.lua file, where the the width is 320px and height 480px(or something like that). I want my app to be versatile, so that you could play it on all devices. Should i change these to

```
    width = display.contentWidth,
    height = display.contentHeight,
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/#contentscaling), what I think you should do instead is to set the width and height to something appropriate for your app, then use the scale option in config.lua. Also available for the scale option is "adaptive", which actually scales the content area according to DPI. This is important if there is going to be a lot of text that might end up being too small on a phone, when it was fine on the desktop version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. I recommended you read about [Content Scaling](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/basics/configSettings/#contentscaling).